# Automatically open apps on iOs - Background Task + Url scheeme

Tags: ios, background-process, url-scheme

Is it possible on iOs to open an app using its url scheme called from a background task (or even a remote notification task)?

What I want to do is:
When my app receives a push notification, It runs a backhround task that will stat another app from its url scheme.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do what you're asking. UIKit methods can only be invoked from the main thread. Refer to the following links that have discussed this problem before:

[openURL is not working when App is in background in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132931/openurl-is-not-working-when-app-is-in-background-in-ios)

[UIApplication openURL background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170254/uiapplication-openurl-background)